# Troubles linking the libnoise library to a project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, libraries

I am still fairly new to C++ and even newer to Visual Studio. I am attempting to link the perlin noise library 'libnoise' ([found here](http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/)) to my visual studio 2010 project, I have searched online for many many hours to no avail, this has been a road block for a few days now.

What are the steps needed to link this library?

The files that are downloaded are a bin folder (contains the .dll and .lib) and a include (headers I believe)

thank you in advance and please correct any mistakes I have made with asking this question.

Comment: Have you tried Loading DLL as `Delay Loaded DLL` in `*Project->Properties -> Linker-> Input-> Delay Loaded Dlls*`

Comment: That didn't appear to solve my problem, I believe it has something to do with adding the path to the project somehow? I'm pretty sure this is an easy thing that everyone should know how to do, but I am apparently at a loss. I have tried looking up tutorials on adding libraries into my project with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to:
1. Add the header directory to `Additional Include Directories` (`PROJECT->Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories`, on drop down select `<Edit...>`)
2. Add the .lib directory to `Additional Library Directories` (`PROJECT->Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories`, same above)
3. Add the .lib names you need to `Additional Dependencies` (`PROJECT->Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies`, same above)
4. After building your project, copy the .dll to your project's build directory, usually at your solution's `Debug` directory ("Solution Path"/Debug) or you would encounter `*.dll is missing` error. You should find "yourapp".exe file there as well.
Good Luck.
Edit: more can be found at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Compiler/Linker/Libraries/Configuring_Visual_Studio

Comment: thank you this was a perfect explanation and the link was a helpful resource.

Comment: sadly this didn't work for me, in vs 2015: between the step 3-4 everything goes to hell, and the linker problem still remains..

Answer (score 0):

You can use nuget.
Open package manager console and type :  Install-Package libnoise